# How to handle multiple parameter in angular 2 router beta?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I'm trying to pass multiple parameter in angular 2 router beta. But got error.

**My app.route.ts file**

```js
export const routes : RouterConfig =[
    {path:'',component:DashboardComponent},
    {path:'login',component:LoginComponent},
    {path:'signup',component:SignupComponent},
    {path:'profile/:type/:name',component:ProfileComponent}
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROViDERS = [
    provideRouter(routes)
];
```

**dashboard.component.ts**

```
export class DashboardComponent{
constructor(private router:Router){

}
profile():void{
    this.router.navigate(['/profile',{type:'artist',name:'mash'}]);
}}
```

**profile.component.ts**

```
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit{
constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute,private router:Router){

}

type:string;
name:string;

ngOnInit(){
    console.log(this.route.snapshot.params);
}}
```

**error**
[image]

What should I try now ? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For route params just use

```
this.router.navigate(['/profile','artist','mash']);
```

The array you added is for query parameters.